# What should be correct approach/template for making anjularJS application within visual studio which will consume C# Web API from the same solution?

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I tried some approaches where First, we can install node.js and create a separate application and can externally consume API create in C#.

Second, i downloaded template from below path,
https://github.com/angular/quickstart

imported it to in VS2015 as guided in below link,
https://code4developers.com/angular-4-application-with-visual-studio/

But still i am confused what should be the correct approach to create angularJS project in visual studio 2015 which will occupy web API within same solution.

Comment: Why using VS2015 and not VS2017?

Comment: VS 2017 has a template for Angular 4+, I suggest you to use that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try with the visual studio 2017.

Comment: I just checked by trying with VS2017. I think its available with .NET Core not with .NET Framework. Please let me know any other steps to take for .NET Framework for the same @JeroenHeier